# Xcode UiListViewController - Broken

Tags: ios, xcode

I know it's not my .php script because my Android Java Script and App works perfectly.  Therefore, I believe my problem lies in my Xcode.

I have a Table View.  This Table View has requests from a list of users (Users A, B, C and D) who are requesting information from another user (User E).

If User E receives the requests in order with A being first then B, C then D but, then User E responds to the request from user D before user A, the information is sent to User A not User D.

I have created a Database of 100 requests, and it has proven that the reply always responds to the earliest request.  It appears to be linking to the RefID() then the actual ID.

My Android app works perfectly.  So, it can't be an issue with the .java or the .php.  It must lie with the Xcode.

Has anyone heard of Xcode's UITableView responding to the number order and not the item chosen?

Is the problem in the code, or is there an option that I have not selected that correlates to the Table List?